# Coldfusion - Memory efficient xlsx/excel generation

Tags: excel, coldfusion, export, xlsx, cfspreadsheet

I am trying to build a excel xlsx workbook using Coldfusion. I am use the various spreadsheetXYZ functions to do so. A problem I have come across is that some of the exports I am running have lots of data, and so it seems memory becomes of concern. My understanding is that the coldfusion spreadsheet functions keep everything in memory until spreadsheetWrite is called.

Is there a more efficient way to generate a workbook, with multiple sheets and lots of data?

Comment: From where is the data sourced? SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? Maybe CF isn't the best way to export volumes of data like this. I've certainly used `cfspreadsheet` to generate Excel files with massive volumes of data, but those exports were batched and handled by servers dedicated to file generation. This avoided impacting the servers / instances that ran the core application.

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/cfsimplicity/spreadsheet-cfml

Spreadsheet CFML - Standalone library for working with spreadsheets in CFML
It has more functionality than the built-in cfspredsheet tag. Most notably for your purposes `newStreamingXlsx` which keeps large excel sheets memory efficient.

```
spreadsheet = New spreadsheet();
workbook = spreadsheet.newStreamingXlsx( streamingWindowSize=10 );

spreadsheet.addRows( workbook, data ); //Data can come from a query/array

spreadsheet.download( workbook,"report.xlsx" );
```

And this is just a simple example, There are many other features included like: `addAutofilter`, `addFreezePane`, `addImage`, `addInfo`, `addPageBreaks`, `writeToCsv`, etc.

Comment: This is great information.  Definite upvote from me.  I've had to do some interesting coding gymnastics in the past to prevent myself from running into memory issues when exporting and formatting large datasets to excel.  I'm bookmarking this and saving this for the future in case I need it.

Comment: Hey @user12031119 Don't bookmark it.  Use it.  In addition to providing lots of new & convenient features, the spreadsheet-cfml library is a lot faster than built-in CFSpreadsheet.